# change date format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I am trying this since last two hours and finaly left it out for you guys :P

I need to convert this **String** `Mon, 14 May 2012, 12:00:55 +0200`
into **Date** `dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss` format..

Any kind of help towards the goal will be really appreciated.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using NSDateFormatter but I am unable to figure out the exact format of the above date.
This `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEddMM,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];` is how I have tried and many other formats too

Eg:

```
 NSString *finalDate = @"Tue, 29 May 2012, 14:24:56 +0200";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEddMM,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finalDate];
```

Here the date alwasys comes as nil

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important part of date formatting is often forgotten, tell the `NSDateFormatter` the input language:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss Z"];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Mon, 14 May 2012, 12:00:55 +0200"];
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

I've checked the output: `date: 2012-05-14 10:00:55 +0000`

Be aware that the `HH` in the date formatter is for `24hr`.

Now I would suggest not to use a fixed output scheme, but use one of the `NSDateFormatterStyle`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```

Which in american english will output: `5/14/12 12:00 PM`

---

This code is valid for `ARC` if you are not using `ARC` add `autorelease` to the `NSLocale` and release the `NSDateFormatter` after you are done with it.

Comment: If vote up didn't required 15 repu I would have done that too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss"];
NSString *formatterDate = [inputFormatter stringFromDate:inDate];
[inputFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

get inforamtion about all Date Formate
my Blog Link is http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html

and also small function is bellow.....

```
-(NSString *) dateInFormat:(NSString*) stringFormat {
 char buffer[80];
 const char *format = [stringFormat UTF8String];
 time_t rawtime;
 struct tm * timeinfo;
 time(&rawtime);
 timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
 strftime(buffer, 80, format, timeinfo);
 return [NSString  stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

////////Like.......

```
NSString *mydate =  [self dateInFormat:@"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"];
```

hope,this help you....